# What is the wire used for hand movement of robot called ? where can I find it online ?

Tags: microcontroller, robotic-arm, movement

I am looking for a specific name of the wire used for the robotic arm movement control and where can I find some of this online. I want to control it using the micro controller so please suggest some good development kit.

Comment: Please clarify your question further. As of now it looks like a shopping question. Something not appreciated by this community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are referring to `robotic tendons`.

[image]

There is a lot of material on the subject if you search google.